# What is the time complexity of String.length() in Java?

Tags: java, time-complexity

Is it O(n) or O(1) (by saving the length in a private variable during string allocation to the object)?

if it is O(n), does it mean that the complexity of following code is O(n^2)?

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1;i++){
    //some code here!
}
```

Comment: FYI java is open source, you can check what it does yourself ;)

Comment: @RamonBoza Actually OpenJDK is open source. Java is a specification and has no intrinsic source code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is `O(1)` as the length is already known to `String` instance.

From JDK 1.6 it is visible.

```
public int length() {
    return count;
}
```

---

Update

It is important to understand why they can cache the value of `count` and keep using same value for `count`. The reason lies in a great decision they took when designing `String`, its Immutability.

Answer (score 5):

In Java any String is backed up by an `final` array. So it is simple to just return the array length. So it is `O(1)` complexity. And if you think in your code

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1;i++){
    //some code here!
}
```

`s.length()` is called for every iteration then you are not right. Modern compiler optimizes this type of call and changes `s.length()` to constant number(i.e the length of the `String` instance).

Answer (score 1):

String internally maintains an **array** of characters and **length of the array is a property** of array object hence O(1) as its simple reading of property.

Comment: What do you mean by array object?

Comment: I have mentioned `array of characters`! And an array in java is an object.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is  `O(1)` Since `String` class have the length as a `field`. It's not O(n^2).