# Palindromes function in java

Tags: java, logic

Could anyone tell me how to write palindromes function in Java
without using String API's?
Is there any inbuilt function in Java API

Comment: You can use a stringbuilder to reverse the string and compare it with itself. But a) your question is unclear (do you need a palindrome test or a generator? b) you should show some tentative before asking.

Comment: your answer is here 
[Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444710/easiest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-palindrome)

Comment: There is no such function that comes with Java itself. The check can be written with a few lines of code though. Or you can find it with google.

Comment: Let me try with apache-commons-palindrome

Comment: Thanks subodh Joshi. It works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursive function also if you do like to do in core logic.
[Here](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/java-program-to-check-palindrome-string-using-recursion/) is the example for you. Have a look if beneficial to you.