# How to make a string "palindrome" from the given string by removing certain characters?

Tags: python

What would be the loop content in the for loop?

```
a=raw_input("Enter a string :")
print a
length = len(a)
p = a[::-1]
print p
if a == p:
   print "palindrome"
else:
   print "Not palindrome"
for i in range(len(a)):
```

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248161/palindrome-detection-efficiency

Comment: your question makes little sense, are you checking for palindromes or trying to manipulate  strings to become palindromes?

Comment: I am trying to manipulate strings to become palindromes. For example string "aaab" is not a palindrome. So, I need to remove b in order to be "aaa" palindrome. So what would be the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the length of the string is odd or even. If odd try to preserve the middle character.

```
if len(s)%2:
    return s[:len(s)//2] + s[len(s)//2] + s[:len(s)//2][::-1]
else:
    return s[:len(s)//2] + s[:len(s)//2][::-1]
```

Answer (score -2):

This checks if string s is a palindrome

```
s='hiih'
s[0:int(len(s)/2)] == s[int(len(s)/2):len(s)][::-1]
```

Comment: It might not answer the vague question. What I state is true however. Why vote down?

Comment: maybe because it does not answer the question, *and* is nowhere near an elegant solution, even buggy? `s==s[::-1]` does the trick, and is far more elegant.

Comment: hm, I'm afraid you're right, I guess I earned this one :-)